# notifying users of backend changes via subscription

Tags: server, push-notification, backend

My mobile app has users who are `clients`, `business owners`, and `employees`.

Each business owner can have multiple businesses.
Clients can create an order with one of the businesses. When they do, the business owner and employees who are linked with the business should be notified.

I have an `orders` collection where I create the order and I add the order doc id to an array of pending orders on the `business` record.

Notifying new order is mission critical, so I cannot depend only on push notifications. So I decided I’ll update the app via a db subscription to the `user` collection.

Sure, I can update an array of orders on records of the owner and employees linked with the business once the order is placed, but it becomes hard to manage when the owner may remove an employee from a business. It's repetitive when storing the order IDs in each employee’s record. It’s also expensive to keep updating these records when orders are processed.

How would you approach this?

**UPDATE**

I'm using [Firebase](http://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Another approach could be storing each order under the business ID, and then have each connected employee and owner listen to changes to that doc. However, it is possible that it will be more expensive as users will need to be listening to more documents than just their own user record.

Comment: To me it seems that the simplest solution is a to store clients, employees, owners and orders as separate entities. Then each order has a reference to a specific business. Each business references a specific owner and each employee a specific business. Now when you need to contact all involved in an order all you need to do is pull up the order, which will by reference give you the business which you then query for their employees. Having said that, without knowing what framework or database you use, this is all pretty much speculation.

Comment: @mydogspies I'm using Firebase - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: The thing is that what you are trying to achieve is exactly what the Firebase cloud database is the weakest at - relational queries. What you are describing is a simple matter of design not to duplicate data and then writing the queries. With some observer patterns you can easily push any data fast to any part of your app. More importantly, you should not mix the database with synchronization of data. Store your data in a proper db then let another part of your business logic do the pushing of orders. Performance is the least of your problems in your current setup.

Comment: @mydogspies thanks, you're absolutely right. It looks like I hit that same issue a lot of people are facing: https://dev.to/spencerpauly/why-i-switched-away-from-google-firestore-3pn. My question, in fact, has no simple answer.